# MINGW32 composer: command not found - windows 8

Tags: git, composer, windows-8, mingw

Olá, eu instalei o git no windows 8 e estou com um problema no "cmd" o composer funciona e no MINGW32 que veio no git aparece a mensagem "composer: command not found" alguém sabe como eu resolvo isto?

OBS: eu já coloquei o caminho do composer.bat na Variável PATH

Comment: Você tem que colocar a pasta de instalação do composer na lista de variáveis de ambiente, presentes na variável `PATH`. Mas acho que se você instalar o composer (via instalador) não tem esse problema no Windows.

Comment: esqueci de postar isso, eu instalei o composer manualmente e eu coloquei o caminho do composer na Variável PATH

Comment: fiz via instalador e funcionou